# Is there official MySQL driver for Tornado Framework?

Tags: python, mysql, tornado

I'm on the point of architecting some socket-based API and i run into problem.

Is there are officially supported MySQL driver for Tornado Framework? I wood use cool and modern async from Python 3.4, but this one don't support MySQL for sure.

And yes, i'm notice couple drivers in https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/wiki/Links, but my problem is - this drivers is kind a old and they don't support Python 3.

Thanks!

Comment: A quick Google search shows that there's a MySQL driver for `asyncio`: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql.

Comment: Another Google search reveals a recently updated MySQL driver for tornado: https://github.com/PyMySQL/Tornado-MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to these links. this is git hub link of PyMySQL fork for Tornado: https://github.com/PyMySQL/Tornado-MySQL

this link is a short doc for MySQLdb DB-API connections: https://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/branch2.4/database.html

you can find the supported python version in this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Tornado-MySQL

as mentioned in the comments you can also see MySQL driver for asyncio: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql , http://aiomysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/